# OneSignal push notification handle in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onesignal

i have problem with handling OneSignal pushNotification in cordova app. My purpose is open display page from any controllers, every page has specific controller. Whenever notification come will do same thing, open display page. My code is here :

index.html

```
 function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
  var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
      //do some thing
  };

  window.plugins.OneSignal
    .startInit("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    .endInit();           
}
```

controller

```
app.controller('startController', function ($scope, $http) {

 var notificationOpenedCallback = function (jsonData) {
    $scope.myNavigator.pushPage('form/displaypage.html');

 };

 window.plugins.OneSignal //get error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OneSignal' of undefined
    .startInit("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
    .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    .endInit();
});
```

How to put `windos.plugins.OneSignal` in controllers?

Answer (score 0):

For cordova apps, you need to add the OneSignal plugin first. In the terminal, at the root of your cordova application, do

`cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin`

If you want to save this plugin to your `config.xml`, add the `--save` flag to the end of the command. This comes in handy if you're using shared version control.

This will install and register the plugin. You should then rebuild the project and try again on your device.

Further information about setup with the Cordova SDK can be found [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk-setup)